# Can 'Beta-hexachlorocyclohexane' (C6H6Cl6) be Optically named?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I have not found RS configuration in Beta-hexachlorocyclohexane(C6H6Cl6) anywhere but tried to give it, although some books say that it can not be named in this configuration. So, is it named correctly, if not what is the mistake?

[image: Beta-hexachlorocyclohexane]

Comment: Welcome to ChemSE. This issue has been [addressed previously on this site](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/110099/why-are-carbons-of-inositol-chiral-centers/110460#110460). If this hexachloride were hexahydroxyl it would be *scyllo*-inositol, which has the lower case "r"-configuration at each carbon. Go to [this link](http://ursula.chem.yale.edu/~chem220/chem220js/STUDYAIDS/isomers/RS14272/inositol.html) for an additional explanation.

Comment: All the atoms have two identical substituents, so how could you get R/S?

Comment: If you rotate the molecule 120 degrees in plane, it is the same molecule which means any S/R assignments must alternate. If you flip the molecule through the horizontal plan, it is the same molecule however all the S configurations would now map to R and vice versa, therefore all centres are both S and R which means they cannot be assigned.

Comment: @Tragamor: Your R/S analysis is not in keeping with CIP rules. All carbons are of the r-configuration and are, therefore, assignable. Follow my links above.

Answer (score 2):

This hexachlorocyclohexane (red box) is one of nine possible stereoisomers in analogy with the [inositols](http://ursula.chem.yale.edu/%7Echem220/chem220js/STUDYAIDS/isomers/RS14272/inositol.html). The isomer in question is of the *scyllo*-configuration and all carbons are of the same configuration. Imagine a molecular model lying on a table. It falls off. You pick it up and place it on the table exactly as before. There are six solutions.
 Configurations at $\ce{C1-C4}$, $\ce{C2-C5}$ and $\ce{C3-C6}$ are RR, SS and SR, respectively, and they are internally inconsistent because all carbons are identical. Given the planes of symmetry through  $\ce{C1-C4}$, $\ce{C2-C5}$ and $\ce{C3-C6}$, each carbon is stereogenic and *achirotopic*. The latter condition requires r/s assignments and not R/S.
To assign the r/s configuration, one constructs a digraph (*vide infra*) where $\ce{C1}$ is the non-duplicate atom and C<sub>(1)</sub> is the duplicate atom, which is attached to three atoms of atomic number zero.  Atoms $\ce{C2-C6}$ are given temporary (R<sub>o</sub>/S<sub>o</sub>) R/S configurations because, in the digraph, these carbons are both stereogenic and *chirotopic*. As an example, $\ce{C2}$ is assigned S<sub>o</sub> because the priorities are Cl>long chain>short chain>H. Likewise, $\ce{C6}$ is R<sub>o</sub>.   Having made temporary assignments for $\ce{C2-C6}$ and realizing that as R>S, as is R<sub>o</sub>>S<sub>o</sub>, the *scyllo*-isomer reduces to Cl>$\ce{C6}$>$\ce{C2}$>H (Cl>R<sub>o</sub>>S<sub>o</sub>>H). $\ce{C1}$ and $\ce{C2-C6}$ all have the r-configuration. Other stereoisomers require [more complex rules](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/110099/why-are-carbons-of-inositol-chiral-centers/110460#110460) for the final assignment.

[image]